# problem with compiling C project in a C++ unit test

Tags: c++, c, googletest

I have a struct forward declaration like below in C
I added googletest and want to test my code using
I added extern "C" in my test.cpp file but I get the error

baseCommand.h file

```
typedef struct Command_t Command_t;

struct Command_t{

    uint8_t id;
    uint8_t procId;
    uint8_t priority;
    char initCommand[50];
    char command[50]; 
    char commandParam[450];
    char finishParam[10];
    int32_t (*fpInit)(struct Command_t* this);
    uint16_t initDelayMs;
    int32_t (*fpSend)(struct Command_t* this);
    uint16_t sendDelayMs;
    int32_t (*fpReceive)(struct Command_t* this);
    char expectedAnswerOnSucessCommand[100];
    char expectedAnswerOnError[100];
    uint16_t receiveDelayMs;
    int32_t (*fpProc)(struct Command_t* this);
    int8_t retry;
    void (*fpReset)(void);
    int port;
    int32_t (*fpCtor)(struct Command_t* this);
};
```

test.cpp file

```
extern "C" {

#include "commands/baseCommand.h"


}

# include "gtest/gtest.h"


TEST(IntegerFunctionTest, negative) {
    
        EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);

}
```

but I got the error (Updated I deleted some not related files )

> expected ',' or '...' before 'this'   baseCommand.h

on line

> int32_t (*fpInit)(struct Command_t* this);

Comment: Why did you typedefed Command_t to Command_t?

Comment: I am forward decalring Command_t to use its pointer inside itself

Comment: A `typedef` is not a forward declaration.  A simple `struct Command_t;` is a forward declaration.

Comment: In C++, the **this** pointer holds the address of current object of a class. You cannot use it here, because it is a keyword.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I changed  `struct Command_t;
typedef struct Command_t{...}` but I got an error 
`unknown type name 'Command_t'` on  `void base_ctor(Command_t *pbase);`

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula yeah I wrote it in C and did not notice that "this " is a reserved  word in C++

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula Why?  OP is compiling this code with both C and C++ compilers.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula I mean that since I had compiled it with gcc I thought that it is correct so I did not notice "this" keyword. All I expect about error were everything unless "this" keyword. I used past verb I mean before finding out "this" is cause

Comment: @s4eed I know it's old, but I just want to leave an "answer" for the future: `typedef struct X X;` is a very common trick in C, used so that you don't have to write `struct X` everywhere where you want to use it. In C++ the semantics were changed and it's not useful anymore (but isn't wrong for code meant for both C and C++).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
int32_t (*fpInit)(struct Command_t* this);
```

You're getting an error because `this` is a keyword in C++ and therefore can't be used as an identifier.  You need to change the name to something else.

Comment: ... and as you, @ahban, have just discovered, `extern "C"` is not a magic "make this work in C++" band-aid.

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code, for q, "I am forward decalring Command_t to use its pointer inside itself - ah ban 28 mins ago"

```
    typedef struct Command_t * Command_tp;

    struct Command_t {

        uint8_t id;
        uint8_t procId;
        uint8_t priority;
        char initCommand[50];
        char command[50];
        char commandParam[450];
        char finishParam[10];
        //int32_t (*fpInit)(struct Command_t* this);
        int32_t (*fpInit)(Command_tp);
        uint16_t initDelayMs;
        //int32_t (*fpSend)(struct Command_t* this);
        int32_t (*fpSend)(Command_tp);
        uint16_t sendDelayMs;
        //int32_t (*fpReceive)(struct Command_t* this);
        int32_t (*fpReceive)(Command_tp);
        char expectedAnswerOnSucessCommand[100];
        char expectedAnswerOnError[100];
        uint16_t receiveDelayMs;
        //int32_t (*fpProc)(struct Command_t* this);
        int32_t (*fpProc)(Command_tp);
        int8_t retry;
        void (*fpReset)(void);
        int port;
        //int32_t (*fpCtor)(struct Command_t* this);
        int32_t (*fpCtor)(Command_tp);
    };
```

Comment: could you explain more what you are intending?